# How to fetch _id field only in array using mongoDB in sailsJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sails.js

I have an issue in retrieve data from `mongoDB` in `sailsJs`. I wanted a pure array of `_id` field, but it returns an array of JSON objects which is something like

```
[
      {_id: 'sdfdsr3434redf'},
      {_id: '6sdgydewu7fr3'}, 
      ...
]
```

but I want only list of IDs like:

```
['sdfdsr3434redf', '6sdgydewu7fr3', ...]
```

**Code is Below:**

```
  let userIDList = await col.find({
                        $or: [
                            {permission: 'student'},
                            {permission: 'staff'}
                        ]
                },{ select : ['_id'] }).toArray();
```

I tried one method and it works well as below (by @atishay_jain),

```
let userIDList = await col.find({
                 $or: [
                      {permission: 'student'},
                      {permission: 'staff'}
                 ]},{ select : ['_id'] }).toArray();

let final = userIDList.map((v, i) => { return v._id });
console.log(final);
```

But I need some short-cuts to do it more relevant. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you using mongoose ODM?

Comment: No, I used mongodb. See.
const { MongoClient, ObjectID } = require('mongodb');

Comment: It's ok, check the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in `javascript`. Here's the code.

```
let userIDList = await col.find({
                 $or: [
                      {permission: 'student'},
                      {permission: 'staff'}
                 ]},{ select : ['_id'] }).toArray();

let final = userIDList.map((v, i) => { return v._id });
console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 1):

After getting all the documents, you need to go through them and parse the value.

Since database query are providing { key: value }, You have to grab the value of the key.

Try this,

```
    let userIDList = [];

    await col.find({
        $or: [
            { permission: 'student' },
            { permission: 'staff' }
        ]
    },{ select : ['_id'] }).toArray().forEach(function(obj) { 
        userIDList.push(obj._id) 
    });
    console.log(userIDList);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in one command, you can try "distinct" command.

```
col.distinct("_id", {
    $or: [{permission: 'student'}, {permission: 'staff'}]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get only _id columns like below

```
let userIDList = await col.find({
                        $or: [
                            {permission: 'student'},
                            {permission: 'staff'}
                        ]
                },{_id:1}).toArray();
```